# c# REST API polymorphic return type

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, polymorphism, response

I have created data contracts as below having inheritance:-

```
[DataContract(Name = "Animal")]
public class Animal { ... }

[DataContract(Name = "Dog ")]
public class Dog : Animal { // Has some Dog specific member properties }

[DataContract(Name = "Cat ")]
public class Cat : Animal { // Has some Cat specific member properties }
```

And I'm using ASP.NET WebApi to provide a REST API like:

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<Animal> Get(string type) 
{ 
    switch(type)
    {
        case "dog":
            Dog dog = GetDogDetails();
            return Task.FromResult(dog);
            break;

        case "cat":
            Cat cat = GetCatDetails();
            return Task.FromResult(cat);
            break:
    }
}
```

I am not able to return the respective animal types. I get the following error:-
"Cannot implicitly convert Dog to Animal".

Also is this polymorphic response a good thing as per REST API standards.

Comment: Whatever the case, thats a horrible error message.

Comment: If you are using JSON, forget data contracts for the nightmare they are and simply return `dynamic` from your controller. Then you can return whatever and it is serialized (as best possible) to the client.

Comment: @zaitsman I would not recommend using dynamic response if needed use  IHttpActionResult as VladStryapko put in his answer.

Comment: @FilipCordas why? Ihttpactionresult requires you to wrap responses in the calls to `this.Ok()` and similar. It is unnecessary code clutter. Your unit tests should ensure the behaviour anyway. The only limitation of this approach is that default xml serialization can't cope with this. But i've used it commercially quite successfully in the past.

Comment: @zaitsman This is an opinion, but to me this just screams lack of architecture. The return of `dynamic` is equivalent to returning an `object` from the controller. And lets say someone dose `case:1 return new { A="" }; case 2 : return Ok(new { A="" });` this will compile and will return same JSON value. And compile time Exceptions are always better then runtime ones.

Comment: @FilipCordas i dont see any issues with the code you provided, other than that it violates DRY. Before that code makes it in, however, i would expect it to go through a peer review and have two unit tests (for cases `1` and `2`), and during said peer review i would question what we are doing from the point of view of maintainability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because you're returning a `Task<T>` and task is not covariant. That is, even though `Dog` is `Animal`, `Task<Dog>` is not `Task<Animal>`.

What can you do?

1. Change your code to be

   ```
       case "dog":
       Animal dog = GetDogDetails();
       return Task.FromResult(dog);
       break;
   ```

You will lose dog's specific properties though.

2. Leverage `Task<IHttpActionResult>` and return `Ok(yourObject)`.

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string type) 
   { 
       switch(type)
       {
           case "dog":
               Dog dog = GetDogDetails();
               return Ok(dog);
               break;

       ...
       }
   }
   ```

I think you should go the second way.

On a second note, I don't really see any reason to use `async/await` here. Why would you use `Task.FromResult`? If your `GetDogDetails` method is `async`, consider `awaiting` it. I don't think you should worry about Tasks in your current code.

> Also is this polymorphic response a good thing as per REST API standards.

I don't know about formal standards but in general it's OK for some objects to have certain properties and for others not to. For instance, imagine a payment system which returns an abstract Event which might or might not have an associated invoice with it.

Comment: You answer is good I just want to add that polymorphic response can be a problem when you do any sort of automated code building (Something like creating documentation). Also depending on serializer configuration you might start to see $type property in the JSON. All this can be a solved but can create a problem.

Comment: @FilipCordas Yeah, I think in case of optional properties I would prefer to simply go with having them in one class and serialising `null` to nothing or to something the clients of the API prefer (if it's an internal API and you can communicate with them).